# Upside down, backwards writing

Tags: neuroanatomy, writing

I am an older adult, who entered college late in life. I came to find out that I have both Dyscalculia, and Dyslexia (formally diagnosed) through great difficulty in college. Not realizing that I had either of those throughout my life. But, in reading the criteria late in life, I find that those diagnoses explain a lot of weird traits, directional, perceptual as well as difficulty remembering. 
I have always been able to write fluently- upside down, backwards, upside down and backwards, with both hands, also forwards upside down. (I am right handed), I also can write normally with both hands. But even still with the added abilities, I cannot learn math, or to read music and I cannot learn other languages. I learn music and repeat it through tone listening.
There has not been a lot of research for comorbidity between Dyslexia and Dyscalculia. I am wondering if anyone has any access to research that would explain my phenomenon.